# how to EDIT button(Name) changed to UPDATE button in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

When i click EDIT button, that row only editable and EDIT button name changed to UPDATE button. After modifying data When i click UPDATE button it will be changed to EDIT. Anybody help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple javascript function to change the value of the button:

```
<apex:commandButton onclick="changeName(this)" ..... />

function changeName(element){
    if(element.value == 'EDIT'){
        element.value = 'UPDATE';    
    }
    else if(element.value == 'UPDATE'){
        element.value = 'EDIT';    
    }
}
```